# How can I track my achievements?

Tags: achievements, android, fruit-ninja-puss-in-boots

I just started playing Fruit Ninja: Puss in Boots on Android and so far it seems that there is a billion achievements, since I've been unlocking them constantly.  However, there's no link to Feint on the home screen (like in the original Fruit Ninja) and I don't see any other way to view (a) what achievements I've gotten or (b) what achievements I have yet to get.

How can I track my achievements?

Comment: The iOS version has a link to Game Center/Feint achievements under Extras (accessible from the strawberry on the main screen). Is it different on Android?

Comment: Also, there are only about 24 achievements. Billion. Pfft.

Comment: @JohnoBoy Is it in the top-right of the Extras screen? On Android there's a blank space there so I'm assuming it's missing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1CY8.png

Comment: Yep, that's the spot where it appears in the iOS version. I can't really help you with your problem, but if you want I can list off the achievements that appear in my game and maybe it'll help you track yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer is, there is no way to track your achievements, on Android.  [Various other users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.halfbrick.fruitninjapib&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oYWxmYnJpY2suZnJ1aXRuaW5qYXBpYiJd) have made the comment that achievements can not be tracked in the current version, for Android.  To quote a few:

> **Excellent, BUT...**
>
> I don't like that you can't view your achievements. What's the point of showing them, if you can't access the proper section for them? Excellent game, but please fix this.
>
> **Great**
>
> Awesome game and would get 5 stars if it had open feint to view acomplishments.... Its on the iphone version, why not here?

Comment: The game shown at that point is the original game, not Puss in Boots.  I don't get sharing icons on the summary screen after playing in PiB and the icons in the Extras section take me straight to the FB and Twitter pages.

Comment: Answer fail.  Sorry, as you can see the title of that previous video was totally wrong.  I edited with what will hopefully be a solution, albeit not within the app.  I recall using some version of this OpenFeint dashboard thing on iOS and on PC, and I think once you get to the D-pad thing you should be able to see achievements for all of your OpenFeint games.

Comment: I didn't try this app (it's not available in the Amazon store and I'm using a Kindle Fire) but judging by searching on the OpenFeint site, this game doesn't actually use Feint on Android.

Comment: Well, after two failed attempts, I just had to find the answer (it's a sickness).  I finally tracked down many others that are having your problem, and it does not seem that there is a current solution.  The fact that a) it does on iOS b) the other Fruit Ninja game does on Android c) Someone posted a YouTube video of the achievements for the old game and called it Puss in Boots - is borderline a campaign of misinformation.  There is a conspiracy under all of this... I just know it.

Comment: Unfortunately you're probably right.  Thanks for sticking with it :P